# API Flickr: How to get only photos that don't have albums?

Tags: flickr, phpflickr

I need to show all the photos for importation into my web application.

First I get albums with:

```
$albums = $flickr->photosets_getList($userId);
```

Then when selected any album, I get the photos with:

```
$photos = $flickr->photosets_getPhotos($albumId);
```

But how to get only photos that don't have albums?

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this method:

```
$photos = $flickr->photos_getNotInSet();
```

Documented in:

[flickr.photos.getNotInSet](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getNotInSet.html)